# How to Convert base64 to Document File txt Format in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, base64

I have return data base64 string. How to view this base64 data in txt file ?

base64 Text:
'data:text/plain;base64,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'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to decode the value you can do a split and then use `atob`. Something like this

```
 const data = '...'
 const text = atob(data.split(",")[1]);
```

Note: this will return the content of the file and not the file itself.

Comment: Thank you. I stuck how to convert this decode to view in txt file.